# Not getting Hidden field value on submitting form in Angular2

Tags: angularjs, angular2-forms, angular-directive

I am initializing a hidden field inside a form

```
<input type="text" name="test" value="{{interest.id}}"  formControlName="test" />
```

On submitting the form I receive empty value of the field value which should be a integer value .

Comment: This field doesn't seem hidden field. Can you please give some more details?

Comment: The field doesn't contain any hidden type, its already text

Answer (score -1):

try this one :

`<input type="text" name="test" [value]="interest.id"  formControlName="test" />`

hope it helps :)